# PCL Gaussian Kernal example

Tags: gaussian, convolution, point-cloud-library, kernel-density

I need help in applying a Gaussian Kernel on my points cloud to smooth the cloud.

I could not figure out how I should write the code and I could not find any plain examples.

Update:

I am using Point Cloud Library (pcl):

```cpp
pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("/home/..../2240.pcd", *raw_cloud);
Eigen::VectorXf horizontal;
//Set up the Gaussian Kernel
pcl::GaussianKernel<pcl::PointXYZRGB> gaussianKernel;
gaussianKernel.compute(5,horizontal,40);

pcl::filters::Convolution<pcl::PointXYZRGB> conv;
conv.setInputCloud(raw_cloud);
conv.setKernel(horizontal);
```

This is the code, it is not complete and I am not sure what if the approach is right?

anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: You need to provide the code you tried and explain why it is that it's not doing what you need it to - including providing sample input and output. Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right way to make a Gaussian Smoothing via PCL:

```cpp
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr inputCloud,cloud;
pcl::filters::Convolution<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB>  convolution;
Eigen::ArrayXf gaussian_kernel(5);
gaussian_kernel << 1.f/16, 1.f/4, 3.f/8, 1.f/4, 1.f/16;
convolution.setBordersPolicy(
                pcl::filters::Convolution<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB>::BORDERS_POLICY_IGNORE);
convolution.setDistanceThreshold (static_cast<float> (0.1));
convolution.setInputCloud (inputCloud);
convolution.setKernel (gaussian_kernel);
convolution.convolve(*cloud);
```

Hope it would help anyone in his work :)

Comment: I ran this code, I really got weird output.  My output is forming like a triangle..